# How to create stored procedure with Null input parameter in "Parallel Datawarehouse?"

Tags: sql-server, parallel-data-warehouse

I am creating a stored procedure to find tables available in a database in Microsoft Parallel Datawarehouse using SSMS 14 with two inputs parameters, name of table and schema.

I tried this syntax for the SQL statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MY_SCHEMA.FIND 
    (@TABLE VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
     @Schema VARCHAR(50) = null)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%' + @TABLE + '%' 
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '%' + @Schema + '%'
END
```

But I got this error:

> CREATE or ALTER PROCEDURE statement uses syntax or features that are not supported in SQL Server PDW.

Please suggest the correct syntax to use

Comment: [You cannot default the values of stored procedures in SQL Data Warehouse](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b735b296-d9c3-4c64-8313-ae01dbad515c/null-parameter-for-stored-procedure?forum=AzureSQLDataWarehouse)

Comment: Why would you want the value to be `NULL` anyway? `'%' + NULL + '%' = NULL`, which would therefore mean that if `@TABLE` or `@Schema` had a value of `NULL` no rows would be returned.

Comment: Larnu, Thank you for reply. to answer your question , there are two scenarios for search 1) user executing Stored procedure know both Table name and Schema name 2) user executing stored procedure know only table name. In second scenarios user won't be able to pass second Parameter required for stored procedure to RUN. so I want to create procedure which can be executed 1) without passing any parameter 2) passing 1 parameter 3) passing both parameter

Comment: @vinayak, I created your SP and it works perfectly on my machine - I have SSMS v17 on SQL Server 1014 Standard...

Comment: @AttieWagner this is related to Azure SQL PDW, it would work on a normal instances of SQL

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available in Azure Synapse Analytics. You can give a feedback on this to Azure feedback forum.
[Azure feedback - SP to accept null params](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/38152690-allow-stored-procedures-to-accept-null-able-input)